# Drag Drop from .NET application to Explorer

Tags: .net, drag-and-drop, explorer

I'm looking to provide users with ability to drag&drop files from grids and other controls in my application into Explorer. 
Any good samples/articles for that?

Comment: Here is some information from the microsoft forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f57ffd5d-0fe3-4f64-bfd6-428f58998603/. I did find a bunch of relevant articles [searching with the title of this post](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Drag+Drop+from+.NET+application+to+Explorer&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=n&sk=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty straight-forward, just call DoDragDrop in a MouseDown event.  You'll need actual files on disk for this to work.

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
   string[] files = new string[] { @"c:\temp\test.txt" };
   this.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files), DragDropEffects.Copy); 
}
```

Comment: This method works perfectly except that it interferes with other events like double click item and click and drag to multi-select. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Sure, use the MouseMove event instead and don't start the drag until it moved far enough.  Not the topic of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample application but it cannot handle large files: [Transferring Virtual Files to Windows Explorer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DataObjectEx.aspx)