# How to drag and drop folders/files from One Windows Explorer to another windows explorer in C#?

Tags: c#

HI,

How to drag and drop folders/files from One Windows Explorer to another windows explorer in C# ?
Internally when i drag and drop from one explorer to another upload should happen
I am using FTP
My requirement is like i have to drag and drop files,folders... to FTP folder in windows explorer ?

Any code snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file already exists you can do it like this: [DoDragDrop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398989/drag-drop-from-net-application-to-explorer/3399771#3399771)

If the file does not exists then this how to do it: [Transferring Virtual Files to Windows Explorer in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DataObjectEx.aspx)

Comment: @Giorgi : This will internally will upload(client -> server drag) where i drag or just it will copy ?

Comment: @Giorgi : My requirement is like I am connecting to a FTP server login it , then returning list of files/folders from there binding it to treeview then opening in windows explorer with the help of process.Start now when i drag and drop some of the item to FTP Server folder internally upload should haapen and if i am dragging n drooping from FTP server folder to local download should happen internally.

Comment: @Swapnil - What will happen when you drop the file depends were you drop it. The main thing is that you should provide the content for the file you dragged.

Comment: @Giorgi :Can i use first Drag and drop in case i am getting files from FTP server and i want to drag to Windows explorer ?

Comment: @Swapnil - what do you mean by first?

Comment: @Giorgi : first link provided by you.

Comment: @Swapnil: The first link requires that the file exists on the local system. If that is the case you can use it. If the file does not yet exist on the local system use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to be the **Drop Target**, you need to enable dropping on the form:

```
AllowDrop = true;
```

At that point, you need to wire up some of the event handlers:

- ItemDrag
- DragOver
- DragEnter
- DragLeave
- DragDrop

So if you had a listbox and wanted to list the files dropped, something like:

```
private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (string fileName in (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) )
   {
       listBox1.Items.Add( fileName );
   }
}
```

To be the **Drop Source**, slightly more work and works best if you actually have a file-name to a real file (see the MSDN link), there is a complete series that describes all of the tricks [Shell Style Drag and Drop in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adamroot/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-wpf-and-winforms) which provides a complete library for you to use.

Some sources:

- [Drag and Drop Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/drag-and-drop-using-C-Sharp/)
- [Drag and Drop using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/drag-and-drop-using-C-Sharp2/) - another one with the same title.
- [How to provide file drag-and-drop functionality in a Visual C# application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/cpp/language-compilers/provide-file-drag-drop-functionality)
- MSDN [Performing Drag-and-Drop Operations in Windows Forms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979)

Comment: I want to drag and drop from my application listview to Windows explorer.

Comment: Do you actually know whether the "file" you are dragging exists?

Comment: Suppose i have binded some folders to treeview and it contains many folders now i want to drag and drop this to FTP folders in windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is pretty close to drag from "item" (just replace the "test.txt" string) to any explorer window (including ftp), when user is moving the item manually.

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { 
   string[] files = new string[] { @"c:\temp\test.txt" };
   this.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files), DragDropEffects.Copy); 
}
```