# Writing a Windows Explorer Clone with drag and drop from Windows in C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

I am trying to create a Window Explorer clone in C#/Visual Studio (that would hopefully look as close to the native explorer as possible) and I need to be able to drag and drop files from this explorer to Windows.  Can anyone link me to any places that would be a good starting point for this kind of project?  Also, any general tips about how I might do this would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drag Drop from .NET application to Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398989/drag-drop-from-net-application-to-explorer)

Comment: @Hans the link you posted too has nothing to do with creating a Window like the "Windows Explorer"

Comment: Mike, questions of the kind "how to do/begin my project" are usually getting closed now.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need these items:

SplitterPanel, TreeView, ListView, AllowDrop=True, System.IO etc